# How can I tell if a textbox input is currently selected?

Tags: javascript, function, input

I just need a function to return true or false if a textbox is selected. I am pretty new to JavaScript so I don't even know if this is possible. Also preferably in JavaScript > jQuery

I have tried onclick but it didn't work. I have also tried many other options shown in other answers but nothing seems to work.

Comment: use onFocus and onBlur

Comment: here is the documentation [Element: focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event)

Comment: Checkout the [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event and the [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

Comment: You have tried many other options? Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned use `.addEventListener('focus', () => {})` it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input element matches the [`:focus` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('focused?', input.matches(':focus'));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input/>
```